# Ubuntu Core and Frame with elo touch 7inch display

Tags: drivers, display

Ubuntu Desktop works well with usb elo touch 7inch display, However moving to Ubuntu Core and Frame the USB elo monitor is NOT recognized.

My question is has anyone tried to interface Core and Frame with a usb display?  Perhaps even a Elo Touch display and or does anyone have any advice on how to gets this working.

Thank you for your responses

Comment: Ubuntu Core is stripped down for IoT applications. There is no desktop environment. What are you using the display for? Are you sure that you're using the appropriate version of Ubuntu for your needs? Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Core are very different products.

Comment: Thought there is no built-in desktop environment, a stock Core install does emit video...mostly to tell the user it's IP address. You can also add snaps that add desktop features. However, those are video signals. Additional snap plug/slot connections are required to access USB. Simply hot-plugging a USB device without any snap connections is supposed to result in AppArmor denying access to the device. That's a feature, not a bug. This question is best asked to the Ubuntu Core and Snap developers at snapcraft.io.